# Enviando e-mail pelo button

Tags: javascript, ajax

No estágio que estou preciso fazer manutenção e desenvolvimento do sistema que utilizam, porém, sou o único no setor de TI e não tenho troca de informações, pois bem. Esta função abaixo ao alterar um campo em específico ele pergunta se você deseja notificar as alterações via E-mail, com um e-mail específico(flTipo=NDVG,flTipo=NDCA,flTipo=NDRA) para cada tipo de campo(VGM,CARGA,DRAFT). Eu precisava aplicar essa forma de enviar email para um button, apenas isso, eu já manipulei o código e efetuei teste de várias formas e não tive sucesso.

Agradeço caso possam me ajudar!

```
function alterarDeadLines(ID_CD_BOOKING,flTipoBL,flTipo){
    $('#formBooking'+ID_CD_BOOKING).find("#acao").val('UDT');   

    $('#formBooking'+ID_CD_BOOKING).find("#flTipo").val(flTipo);
    $('#formBooking'+ID_CD_BOOKING).find("#flTipoBL").val(flTipoBL);

    $('#formBooking'+ID_CD_BOOKING).submit()    

    if( flTipo == "VGM" ){ 

        $("#dialog-confirm").attr("title","Notificar alterações<i class='icon-help'></i>");
        $("#dialog-confirm").find("p").html("Deseja notificar por e-mail as altera&ccedil;&otilde;es realizadas?<br><br>");
        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
            resizable: false,   modal: true,
            width: 500,         height:300,             
            buttons: {
                "Não desejo": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                "Notificar alterações": function() {
                    $('#formBooking'+ID_CD_BOOKING).find("#flTipo").val("NDVG"); 
                    $('#formBooking'+ID_CD_BOOKING).find("#flTipoBL").val("");

                    dataString  = $("#formBooking"+ID_CD_BOOKING).serialize();   
                    $("#btnBoxDefaultAjax").attr('href','anexos-form.asp?'+dataString).click();  
                    $(this).dialog("close");                        
                }
            }
        }); 
    }else if( flTipo == "Carga" ){ 

        $("#dialog-confirm").attr("title","Notificar alterações<i class='icon-help'></i>");
        $("#dialog-confirm").find("p").html("Deseja notificar por e-mail as altera&ccedil;&otilde;es realizadas?<br><br>");
        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
            resizable: false,   modal: true,
            width: 500,         height:300,             
            buttons: {
                "Não desejo": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                "Notificar alterações": function() {
                    $('#formBooking'+ID_CD_BOOKING).find("#flTipo").val("NDCA"); 
                    $('#formBooking'+ID_CD_BOOKING).find("#flTipoBL").val("");

                    dataString  = $("#formBooking"+ID_CD_BOOKING).serialize();   
                    $("#btnBoxDefaultAjax").attr('href','anexos-form.asp?'+dataString).click();  
                    $(this).dialog("close");                        
                }
            }
        }); 
    }else if( flTipo == "Draft" ){ 

        $("#dialog-confirm").attr("title","Notificar alterações<i class='icon-help'></i>");
        $("#dialog-confirm").find("p").html("Deseja notificar por e-mail as altera&ccedil;&otilde;es realizadas?<br><br>");
        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
            resizable: false,   modal: true,
            width: 500,         height:300,             
            buttons: {
                "Não desejo": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                "Notificar alterações": function() {
                    $('#formBooking'+ID_CD_BOOKING).find("#flTipo").val("NDRA"); 
                    $('#formBooking'+ID_CD_BOOKING).find("#flTipoBL").val("");

                    dataString  = $("#formBooking"+ID_CD_BOOKING).serialize();   
                    $("#btnBoxDefaultAjax").attr('href','anexos-form.asp?'+dataString).click();  
                    $(this).dialog("close");                        
                }
            }
        }); 
    }   
}
```

Comment: Bom, veja isso: `$('#formBooking'+ID_CD_BOOKING).find("#flTipo")`... Não faz sentido _buscar_ um elemento pelo id, já que um id **deve se único** na página. Deveria ser: `$("#flTipo")`... então só aí seu HTML já tem problemas.

Comment: Vc só deve usar `.find()` pra buscar um descendente pela classe, nome da tag, atributo etc., nunca pelo id. Até funciona, porque vc vai forçar um id buscar outro id descendente, mas é errado pelas especificações HTML repetir id.

Comment: Você já tem o código `ASP`, presumo que seu backend seja `ASP` por conta `$("#btnBoxDefaultAjax").attr('href','anexos-form.asp?'+dataString).click();`, para gerar o email? Caso já tenha coloque o código na pergunta, também coloque o html pois precisamos saber o que vai ser serializado `$("#formBooking"+ID_CD_BOOKING).serialize()`

Comment: Eu tenho sim @AugustoVasques porém só o anexo-form.asp tem mais de 800 linhas, existe uma maneira de eu anexar o arquivo? E o que o serialize faz? Transforma o objeto pra string concatenada ?

Comment: Coloque as partes relevantes, os endpoints que são utilizados nesse código. Quanto ao [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: Compreendi o Serialize @AugustoVasques obrigado. Sobre o código, achei melhor deixar ele completo para que pudesse ler melhor. https://jsfiddle.net/nof6dpme/ Deixei nesse jsfiddle na parte de html. Obrigado pela atenção cara.

Comment: A noite e dou uma olhada com calma.